# How to use gsub with a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, gsub

Hey I've a little problem, I've a string array text_word and I want to replace some letters with my file transform.txt, my file looks like this:

```
/t/ 3

/$/ 1

/a/ !
```

But when I use gsub I get an Enumerator back, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
text_transform= Array.new
new_words= Array.new
File.open("transform.txt", "r") do |fi|
  fi.each_line do |words|
    text_transform << words.chomp
  end
end

text_transform.each do |transform|
  text_word.each do |words|
    new_words << words.gsub(transform)
  end
end
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the documentation of `String#gsub`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future programmers don't stumble across the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` returns an `Enumerator` when you provide just one argument (the pattern). If you want to replace just add the replacement string:

```rb
pry(main)> 'this is my string'.gsub(/i/, '1')
"th1s 1s my str1ng"
```

You need to refactor your code:

```rb
text_transform = Array.new
new_words = Array.new
File.open("transform.txt", "r") do |fi|
  fi.each_line do |words|
    text_transform << words.chomp.strip.split # "/t/ 3" -> ["/t/", "3"]
  end
end

text_transform.each do |pattern, replacement| # pattern = "/t/", replacement = "3"
  text_word.each do |words|
    new_words << words.gsub(pattern, replacement)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-gsub)

> If the second argument is a `Hash`, and the matched text is one of its
>   keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

Also you can use [`IO::readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/IO.html#method-c-readlines)

```
File.readlines('transform.txt', chomp: true).map { |word| word.gsub(/[t$a]/, 't' => 3, '$' => 1, 'a' => '!') }
```